# Accessing subclass constructor/methods in static base class method

Tags: matlab, class, oop, constructor, subclassing

I have an abstract base class `Parent`, and two subclasses, `Child1` and `Child2`. Both children implement a static method defined abstractly by the parent, `myStaticTransform`.

The goal is to create a static method, `myStaticBuilder`, in Parent which does some calculations, calls the appropriate `myStaticTransform` method, and then creates an instance of the appropriate child class with that data. Right now I have this defined as an instance method, as so.

```matlab
% Parent.m
function child = myNotStaticBuilder(this)

    % Do complicated math
    x = 1 + 2;

    % Transform the data (using this means the child class will dispatch its appropriate method
    y = this.myStaticTransform(x); 

    % Get the child constructor the only way I know (it's gross and I hate it but shrug emoji)
    childConstructor = str2func(class(this));

    % Return the appropriate child object
    child = childConstructor(y);
end
```

This is not appeasing, but it works, so I can live with it. As far as I've seen, this is how the internet thinks this should be done. Fine.

But ideally, I'd want to make this function static, since it does not rely on any object existing before it is called. If this was static, obviously I wouldn't be able to reference `this` (is it obvious I'm a Python programmer). Without that reference, I don't know how I would get access to the child constructor. As far as I can tell, I would also have to call `Parent.myStaticTransform`, which I think (but haven't verified) would throw an error because the parent implementation is abstract.

Is there a way to turn this into a static method, as I want, or should I just be thankful that Matlab has classes and not expect them do it right?

In Python, I would use a class method instead of a static method, which is a concept that Matlab does not have as far as I know.

```py
@classmethod
def myClassBuilder(cls):

    # Do complicated math
    x = 1 + 2;

    # Transform the data 
    y = cls.myStaticTransform(x)

    # Return the appropriate child object
    child = cls(y)
    return child
```

Comment: How would you get a reference to a child constructor in a static method in Python? I don’t understand how this would be possible in any language? If you don’t have an object, you don’t have a class to reference.

Comment: @CrisLuengo edited my post to explain. I would use a classmethod instead of a static method, which Matlab does not have an equivalent of.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do you call this class method? As `Child.myClassBuilder()`? Not as `Parent.myClassBuilder()`, because then you still don’t know which child’s class method to call.

Comment: I was thinking, if that is the case, why not make a free function that you call as `myClassBuilder('Child')`?

Comment: Yeah, in Python it would be called as Child1/2.myClassBuilder(), even though it's defined in the Parent class. That's the functionality I would hope for.

And I could make that separate function, but I don't think it's a better solution than just keeping the method as an instance method and creating a placeholder child instance to call the method with. Again, this isn't a bad solution per se, I would just like to do it "the right way" if the functionality exists.

Comment: I just think that `myClassBuilder('Child')` is better syntax than `Child().myClassBuilder`, especially if you want to enforce some sort of requirements in the constructor, or if you need object of this class to have resources attached. In these cases, `Child()` might be illegal or very expensive. Anyway, I don't think it is possible to do `Child.myClassBuilder` and have the `myClassBuilder` method know which class it was called for.